# ng-change not working in Ionic after the first change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a simple currency calculator using angular ng-change directive and Ionic Framework.

I can enter data on any of the inputs and the other 2 changes as expected, but I can only do this once, if I try to change another textbox without refreshing, the code stop working (only 1 textbox works instead of 2, or none textbox changes)

This is my view code :

```
<ion-content>
    <h1>Enter Amount</h1>

    <h3> Ether </h3>
    <label class="item item-input">
         <i class="icon ion-social-usd placeholder-icon"></i>
         <input type="number" placeholder="ETH" ng-model="eth" ng-change="ethChange(eth)">
    </label>    

    <h3> Chilean Peso (CLP) </h3>
    <label class="item item-input">
         <i class="icon ion-social-usd placeholder-icon"></i>
         <input type="number" placeholder="CLP" ng-model="ethToCLP" ng-change="clpChange(ethToCLP)">
    </label>

    <h3> Dollars </h3>
    <label class="item item-input">
         <i class="icon ion-social-usd placeholder-icon"></i>
         <input type="number" placeholder="USD" ng-model="ethToUSD" ng-change="usdChange(ethToUSD)">
    </label>

  </ion-content>
```

Controller

```
  $scope.ethChange = function(eth) {
    $scope.ethToCLP = eth * 30000
    $scope.ethToUSD = eth * 50
      };

  $scope.usdChange = function(usd) {
  $scope.eth = usd/50
  $scope.ethToCLP = usd * 650
};

  $scope.clpChange = function(clp) {
  $scope.eth = clp/30000
  $scope.ethToUSD = clp/650
};
```

Exchange rates are for testing purpose only.

I tried many solutions out there in stackoverflow but none worked for me

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the same ng-model for all three inputs and use a different conversion formula for each.

Comment: Thanks! , and how do I pass the parameter or change text value if all textboxes are called the same? regards

Comment: Alright, so they should all use the same model, meaning the same data, but you can apply different modification functions to each individually.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. It works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/lIOarfToHlD93PtsTzId?p=preview).

Comment: Thats exactly what I need but it is not working in my ionic project. How can be this related  to ionic ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put breakpoints on your code and check the values. It is possible that your formula returns the same value. Debug the ng-change functions of each textbox